# Is there an idiomatic way to dry up similar function definitions in clojure?

Tags: clojure, macros, dry

I started with the following code (imagine more than this, but I think this gets the point across):

```
(defn fun1 [arg] {:fun1 arg})
(defn funA [arg] {:funA arg})
(defn funOne [arg] {:funOne arg})
(defn funBee [arg] {:funBee arg})

(defn -main [& args] (prn (fun1 "test-data")))
```

My next pass rendered it so:

```
(defmacro item-defn [a]
  `(defn ~(symbol a) [arg#] {~(keyword a) arg#}))
(item-defn "fun1")
(item-defn "funA")
(item-defn "funOne")
(item-defn "funBee")
(defn -main [& args] (prn (fun1 "test-data")))
```

Is there a way to get this down to something like:

```
(defmacro item-defn [a]
  `(defn ~(symbol a) [arg#] {~(keyword a) arg#}))
(map #(item-defn %) ["fun1" "funA" "funOne" "funBee"])
(defn -main [& args] (prn (fun1 "test-data")))
```

(I tried that in the repl, and it seems to work, but when I load a clj file with it in it, then it doesn't work.  It gives me a "CompilerException" "Unable to resolve symbol: fun1")

Am I misusing macros? How would you do this?

Comment: `{fun1: arg}` should this be a leading `:` instead of a trailing one? since you used `keyword` in the macro, i guess this is a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may define another macro for this purpose, e.g.:

```clj
(defmacro item-defn [a]
  `(defn ~(symbol a) [arg#] {~(keyword a) arg#}))

(defmacro items-defn [& names]
  `(do ~@(for [n names] `(item-defn ~n))))
```

then you'll be able to use it to define any number of functions:

```
(items-defn "fun1" "funA" "funOne" "funBee")
```

Comment: Could you explain why you added the "~@"?  It seems to work without it, but I'm afraid I'm missing some subtlety.

Comment: @JBristow do you mean my edit (I replaced (cons 'do coll) with `(do ~@coll), or you just want me to explain what ~@ do in general case?

Comment: Both versions are exactly the same. This one is slightly shorter and use more idiomatic `~@` construct, but essentially they are the same and produce exactly the same code.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you `map` expression really works in the REPL. I suspect that the `fun1` and `funA` functions you have are still in your REPL because you first eval-ed `(item-defn "fun1")` and `(item-defn "funA")`. On my box I get:

```
(map #(item-defn %) ["fun1" "funA"])
;=> (#'user/p1__22185# #'user/p1__22185#)
```

So no function is defined with name `fun1` or `funA`. The problem is that `map` is a function and `item-defn` is a macro. What happens in your `map` epxression is that `item-defn` gets macroexpanded at compile time at which moment the strings with function names are not visible. The macroexpander has no way of knowing that you want to use `"fun1"` as a name for your to be `defn`-ed function. Instead the macroexpander just sees `%` and then uses a gen-symed name as name of the `defn`-ed function. The `map` expression is evaluated at runtime but then it is too late for the macroexpanded function to do anything with the supplied strings.

The solution of Leonid works because he uses another macro to iterate over the function names. So that the iteration also happens at compile time. You see, macros are kind of contagious. Once you start, you cannot stop.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your macro, the name is already a symbol so you can do:

```
(defmacro item-defn [name]
  `(defn ~name [arg#] {~(keyword name) arg#}))
```

then

```
(item-defn fun1)
```

Comment: That's helpful, but doesn't answer the question.  I still can't use those functions in the file that does the map.  Editing the question to be more clear on what I'm asking.